# react redux don't show getStore

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React Redux.

It's fantasic so that
I want to see about tasks state of Store.
but don't see it.

**result**

tasks: [undefined]

**Ask**

so how can I?

**here code:**

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const initalState = {
    tasks: []
}


function tasksReducer(state = initalState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TASK':
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: state.tasks.concat([action.task])
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const addTask = (task) => ({
    type: 'ADD_TASK',
    payload: {
        task
    }
})


const store = createStore(tasksReducer)


store.dispatch(addTask('like it'))

console.log(store.getState()) <-- here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your action. It's adding a task with a key of `payload`, but you're trying to concat it with `action.task` (Which doesn't exist).

The object that would be sent into your reducer would look like this:

```
{
    type: 'ADD_TASK',
    payload: {
        task: 'like it'
    }
}
```

You can see clearly here, `action.task` doesn't exist, but `action.payload.task` does. Either change the object around, or modify it so you can access it at `action.task`:

```
const addTask = (task) => ({
    type: 'ADD_TASK',
    task
})
```

**Or**, modify your reducer:

```
function tasksReducer(state = initalState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TASK':
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: state.tasks.concat([action.payload.task])
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**In the future:** a bit of debugging would have gone a long way here (And avoided this question altogether). A simple `console.log(action)` at the top of your reducer, would log the above object, and you could infer based on why it's trying to add undefined why it wouldn't work.